# Initialize a public variable

Tags: vb.net, variables, public

I am trying to initialize a public variable in vb.net 2013  in a form  and set a value for it from data grid view and then use it value in anther form put when i use the value of it is zero

here is the initialization

```
Public IdSt As Long
```

set value for it

```
        IdSt = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
```

and this is where i use it

```
Dim std As Long
    If logIn.flag = True Then

        std = logIn.idstu
    Else

        std = CourseReq.IdSt
    End If
```

Comment: vba <> vb.net.  I have removed the vba tag.

Comment: Please do not put tags in the title. I have removed it.  Please read [ask] AndAlso take the [tour].  You may be confusing access level (`Public`) with `Scope`.  Who can see/use `Idst` depends on ***where*** it is decalred

Comment: So what is your question? What is the problem?

Comment: I Have a problem that I am using multiple form in vb 
when i declare a public variable and assign the value of it from a data grid view 
 then call it in another form the value of the variable is zero

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you aren't referencing the correct object.

Let me example, if you have two forms called MainForm and SecondForm and declare them like this:

```
Dim myMainForm as New MainForm
Dim mySecondForm as New SecondForm
```

If you try to access IdSt by doing **MainForm**.IdSt, that is not the same as **myMainForm**.IdSt.

So make sure you can access the actual main form object that you set the variable on.

Comment: the from name is same and i am sure of that , when i try to show the value of the variable  in same form the output is correct put when i call it in different form the value become 0 so i think the form just print the initial value

Comment: i am sorry ,i have a bad English

Comment: Do not use the same form name. Make sure the object has a different name than the class, like in my example above. Then you should find the problem.